# Updating SQL Server from a Filemaker Pro frontend

Tags: sql, sql-server, filemaker

The basic position I have is that my SQL Server database can be queried into Excel, but that's the only front end I have for it. With regards to updating and adding new information, it's not really possible for the eventual end user to do it (there aren't forms like in Access, for example).

I have an option of using Filemaker Pro as a pretty front end which is friendly for the users and can allow me to work happily in SQL.

Would I or end users be able to update the SQL Server database via Filemaker Pro and the ODBC connection back to SQL Server. An example might be adding a new client or adding a piece of new information on an existing client, such as which bank they use.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? Did you find a problem when trying?

Comment: It's [possible](http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/odbc.19.1.html#1027500), but if you're not already familiar with Filemaker, using it (solely) as the front end for an SQL database is not a smart choice, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, FileMaker can do all CRUD actions for records on SQL tables if you have the appropriate ODBC plugin installed.

John Christopher Jones went into a bit more detail in his response to your prior question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27054113/700091